# Expand/Collapse Issue

Tags: jquery

I want to expand/collapse only one container at a time. When I click on first container second container should collapse and when second container expanded, first container should collapse automatically. Following is the Fiddle. Please guide... Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/eK8X5/1138/

```
 jQuery

 $(".header").click(function () {
     $header = $(this);
     $content = $header.next();    
     $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
         $header.text(function () {
             return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: why not use accordion ? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this line to your click handler:

```
$(".header").not(this).text('Expand').next().slideUp();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/1139/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can find any expanded `content` element and then collapse it like

```
$('.content').not($content).stop(true).filter(':visible').slideUp(500, function(){
    $(this).prev().text('Expand')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XDsB8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(".content").not($content).slideUp();
```

before you call the slideToggle function and ofcourse dont forget to update the text of the header