# JQuery div display, collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not a jquery specialist but I have managed to make this script working on my website:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#open_#div_hidden_1').click(function() {
if ($('#div_hidden_1').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#div_hidden_1').show(500);
        $('#div_hidden_1').hide(500);


} else {
        $('#div_hidden_1').hide(500);
}
});
});

</script>
```

Basicly it displays and collapses a div (distinguished by id), I have many divs on my wbesite that are displayed this way(its an inline code, for each div separate code) What I would like to do with it is to close all other divs (e.g. from the same class) when I open another one. Could please someone help me to modify this code so that it will collapse all other divs form the same class?

Comment: Show your HTML and which `class`?

Comment: please provide some HTML -  it looks like you have duplicate ID's and you may benefit from using a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple DIVs and class like below,

```
<div class="divClass">A</div>
<div class="divClass">B</div>
<div class="divClass">C</div>
```

then, you need to use like,

```
$(".divClass").click(function(){
    $(".divClass").hide(500); //hiding all the element with divClass
    $(this).show(500); // showing up the clicked element.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[This might be able to you](http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/1139/)**
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984130/expand-collapse-issue)
Just a part of code

```
$(".header").click(function () {
    $(".header").not(this).text('Expand').next().slideUp();
    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```